# frequency of a letter in a string

Tags: ruby, hash, iterator, each

When trying to find the frequency of letters in 'fantastic' I am having trouble understanding the given solution:

```
def letter_count(str)
  counts = {}

  str.each_char do |char|
    next if char == " "
    counts[char] = 0 unless counts.include?(char)
    counts[char] += 1
  end

  counts
end
```

I tried deconstructing it and when I created the following piece of code I expected it to do the exact same thing. However it gives me a different result.

```
blah = {}
x = 'fantastic'
    x.each_char do |char|
        next if char == " "
        blah[char] = 0 
            unless 
            blah.include?(char)
            blah[char] += 1
    end
blah
end
```

The first piece of code gives me the following

```
puts letter_count('fantastic')
>
{"f"=>1, "a"=>2, "n"=>1, "t"=>2, "s"=>1, "i"=>1, "c"=>1}
```

Why does the second piece of code give me

```
puts blah
>
{"f"=>0, "a"=>0, "n"=>0, "t"=>0, "s"=>0, "i"=>0, "c"=>0}
```

Can someone break down the pieces of code and tell me what the underlying difference is. I think once I understand this I'll be able to really understand the first piece of code. Additionally if you want to explain a bit about the first piece of code to help me out that'd be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't split this line...

```
counts[char] = 0 unless counts.include?(char)
```

... over multiple line the way you did it.  The trailing conditional only works on a single line.

If you wanted to split it over multiple lines you would have to convert to traditional if / end (in this case unless / end) format.

```
unless counts.include?(char)
  counts[char] = 0
end
```

Here's the explanation of the code...

```
# we define a method letter_count that accepts one argument str
def letter_count(str)

  # we create an empty hash 
  counts = {}

  # we loop through all the characters in the string... we will refer to each character as char
  str.each_char do |char|

    # we skip blank characters (we go and process the next character)
    next if char == " "

    # if there is no hash entry for the current character we initialis the 
    # count for that character to zero
    counts[char] = 0 unless counts.include?(char)

    # we increase the count for the current character by 1
    counts[char] += 1

  # we end the each_char loop
  end

  # we make sure the hash of counts is returned at the end of this method 
  counts

# end of the method
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that @Steve has answered your question and you have accepted his answer, perhaps I can suggest another way to count the letters.  This is just one of many approaches that could be taken.

**Code**

```
def letter_count(str)
  str.downcase.each_char.with_object({}) { |c,h|
    (h[c] = h.fetch(c,0) + 1) if c =~ /[a-z]/ }
end
```

**Example**

```
letter_count('Fantastic')
  #=> {"f"=>1, "a"=>2, "n"=>1, "t"=>2, "s"=>1, "i"=>1, "c"=>1}
```

**Explanation**

Here is what's happening.

```
str = 'Fantastic'
```

We use [String#downcase](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase) so that, for example, `'f'` and `'F'` are treated as the same character for purposes of counting. (If you don't want that, simply remove `.downcase`.) Let

```
s = str.downcase #=> "fantastic"
```

In

```
s.each_char.with_object({}) { |c,h| (h[c] = h.fetch(c,0) + 1) c =~ /[a-z]/ }
```

the enumerator [String#each_char](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) is chained to [Enumerator#with_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index).  This creates a compound enumerator:

```
enum = s.each_char.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "fantastic":each_char>:with_object({})>
```

We can view what the enumerator will pass to the block by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["f", {}], ["a", {}], ["n", {}], ["t", {}], ["a", {}],
  #    ["s", {}], ["t", {}], ["i", {}], ["c", {}]]
```

(Actually, it only passes an empty hash with `'f'`; thereafter it passes the updated value of the hash.)  The enumerator `with_object` creates an empty hash denoted by the block variable `h`.

The first element `enum` passes to the block is the string `'f'`. The block variable `c` is assigned that value, so the expression in the block:

```
(h[c] = h.fetch(c,0) + 1) if c =~ /[a-z]/
```

evaluates to:

```
(h['f'] = h.fetch('f',0) + 1) if 'f' =~ /[a-z]/
```

Now

```
c =~ /[a-z]/
```

is `true` if and only if `c` is a lowercase letter.  Here

```
'f' =~ /[a-z]/ #=> true
```

so we evaluate the expression

```
h[c] = h.fetch(c,0) + 1
```

`h.fetch(c,0)` returns `h[c]` if `h` has a key `c`; else it returns the value of [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)'s second parameter, which here is zero. (`fetch` can also take a block.)

Since `h` is now empty, it becomes

```
h['f'] = 0 + 1 #=> 1
```

The enumerator `each_char` then passes `'a'`, `'n'` and `'t'` to the block, resulting in the hash becoming

```
h = {'f'=>1, 'a'=>1, 'n'=>1, 't'=>1 }
```

The next character passed in is a second `'a'`.  As `h` already has a key `'a'`,

```
h[c] = h.fetch(c,0) + 1
```

evaluates to

```
h['a'] = h['a'] + 1 #=> 1 + 1 => 2
```

The remainder of the string is processed the same way.